# Importing python variable from a file in directory to main file

Tags: python, import, module

I have project:

```
/app
     main.py
     __init__.py
    /directory1
        a.py
        b.py
        __init__.py

    /directory2
        c.py
        d.py
        __init__.py
```

/x - folder x

This is my code in order to import

```
from directory2 import c
new_var = c.variable
```

If it's important, I'am using FastApi
And I need variable from directory2, c.py file import to main.py. What should I do? I would need a clear answer: do this (and it will work). Thank you in advice!

An Error:
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\app\main.py", line 3, in 
from directory2 import c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: No ;/ because I am working with other people on this project

Comment: In main.py you write:
from  directory2.c  import  my_variable 
 
print(my_variable)